# How to disassemble an array of objects and nested arrays to Separated arrays with single data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, nested-loops

i have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    alert_count: 3
    alert_level: {value: 0, label: "ignore"}
    count_dates: (3) ["2021-04-21T14:36:02.446Z", "2021-04-21T14:36:12.039Z", "2021-04-21T14:37:04.495Z"]
    sound_type: {_id: "606331d3b0e1706ec7e55598", sound_type: "Finger snapping"}
    sensor: {     
      sound_files: (3) ["60803852d78352ad8784220b", "6080385bd78352e29d84220d", 60803890d7835296b684221a"] 
   }
]
```

i need to disassemble the object by 'count_dates:' and 'sound_files:' and create 3 objects with one date & sound file each. like this:

```
[
 {
    alert_count: 1
    alert_level: {value: 0, label: "ignore"}
    count_dates: (1) ["2021-04-21T14:36:02.446Z"]
    sound_type: {_id: "606331d3b0e1706ec7e55598", sound_type: "Finger snapping"}
    sensor: {     
      sound_files: (1) ["60803852d78352ad8784220b"] 
   },
{
    alert_count: 1
    alert_level: {value: 0, label: "ignore"}
    count_dates: (1) [ "2021-04-21T14:36:12.039Z"]
    sound_type: {_id: "606331d3b0e1706ec7e55598", sound_type: "Finger snapping"}
    sensor: {     
      sound_files: (1) [ "6080385bd78352e29d84220d"] 
   },
{
    alert_count: 1
    alert_level: {value: 0, label: "ignore"}
    count_dates: (1) [ "2021-04-21T14:37:04.495Z"]
    sound_type: {_id: "606331d3b0e1706ec7e55598", sound_type: "Finger snapping"}
    sensor: {     
      sound_files: (1) [60803890d7835296b684221a"] 
   }
];
```

i tryed using loops, filtering, map + filter.

example:

```
const result = alert.filter(({ count_dates }) => count_dates.some( ({ alert }) => dateToString(alert) === dateToString(date - 1) ) );
```

here i tried to get only the alerts of yesterday but it gave me all alerts who has the date in the array, it doesnd brake or splite the array to single arrays. i also tried to do nested forEach FN, does'nt Work

the closest i got is an array of all dates withut the other data...

i hope someone can help me with it :-)

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: const result = alert.filter(({ count_dates }) =>
    count_dates.some(
      ({ alert }) => dateToString(alert) === dateToString(date - 1)
    )
  );
here i tried to get only the alerts of yesterday but it gave me all alerts who has the date in it' it doesnd brake or splite the array to single arrays. i also tried to do nested forEach FN, does'nt Work

Comment: hi, please edit the question to add the code.  Also what language are you working with?

Comment: working with React js

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
var a =[
{
  alert_count: 3,
  alert_level: {value: 0, label: "ignore"},
  count_dates: ["2021-04-21T14:36:02.446Z", "2021-04-21T14:36:12.039Z", "2021-04-21T14:37:04.495Z"],
  sound_type: {_id: "606331d3b0e1706ec7e55598", sound_type: "Finger snapping"},
sensor: {     
  sound_files: ["60803852d78352ad8784220b", "6080385bd78352e29d84220d", "60803890d7835296b684221a"] 
}}];

console.log(a);

var mapped = a.map(function(item){
  var ret = []; 
  for(var i=0;i<item.alert_count;i++){
     ret.push({
            alert_count: 1,
            alert_level: item.alert_level,
            count_dates: item.count_dates[i],
            sound_type: item.sound_type,
            sound_file: item.sensor.sound_files[i]
     });
   
  }
  return ret;
})

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: thank you!!!! i hope this will work for my analytics 
for loop... so simple, so elegant :-)